# Find the regular expression

Tags: php, regex

There is a line containing this:

```
function dekorator($func, $agrs = [])
{
    if (dd){
        var_dump("dekorators");

        $func();
    }
}

if (true)
{
    @dekorator
    function test()
    {
        if (ss){
            var_dump("tests");
            while(){
                dd
            }
        }
    }

    function dgdg()
    {
        var_dump("ff");
    }

    test();
}
```

I need to get the following:

1. Function name
2. Function Parameters
3. The function body (inside the quotes {} relating only to the
   function)

I wrote a regular expression:

```
/function?\s+(\w+)*\(([^\)]*)\).*?\{([^\}]+[^\{]+)\}/sim
```

But there is one BUT, the last function it captures is not the quotation mark (which concerns not the function itself)

The function itself:

```
function dgdg()
{
    var_dump("ff");
}
```

Superfluous:

```
    test();
}
```

**DEMO**: https://regex101.com/r/MTS1pr/1/

Comment: If you had this in class, then you could use http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php

Comment: @Justinas, the point is that this is a string

Comment: i think it's not really possible to do it in regex actually, there is too much edge case, and reg exp wasn't design for this kind of works, and still not perfect. But you could do a state machine to parse your string correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this expression:

```
function\s+(\w*)\s*\((.*?)\)\s*(\{((?>[^{}]+|(?3))*)\})
```

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/o0t3fY/2

Comment: Thanks a lot, yesterday I thought of this kind of regular expression

Comment: `function\s([^\)]+)\((.*?)\)\s*(\{(.*$|[^{}]|(?3))*\})`